# strcmp or string::compare?

Tags: c++, c, string, char, string-comparison

I want to compare two strings. Is it possible with `strcmp`? (I tried and it does not seem to work). Is `string::compare` a solution?

Other than this, is there a way to compare a `string` to a `char`?

---

Thanks for the early comments. I was coding in C++ and yes it was `std::string` like some of you mentioned.
I didn't post the code because I wanted to learn the general knowledge and it is a pretty long code, so it was irrelevant for the question.

I think I learned the difference between C++ and C, thanks for pointing that out. And I will try to use overloaded operators now. And by the way `string::compare` worked too.

Comment: "seems like not working" - can you be more specific? What are the parameters and what is the result?

Comment: If you're programming in C++ then you should use C++ idioms, which means C++ `string` and its associated methods. For C use C idioms, such as `char *` and `strcpy`.

Comment: what do you mean by "seems like not working"?

Comment: "I tried and seems like not working" => post the code you used, the results you expected and what you got. And also you should specify what you mean with "string" (C-style ASCIIZ string? `std::string`? Something else?) and what you mean with "compare a string to a char" (it makes no sense, it's like comparing apples to oranges).

Comment: @Matteo Italia, It doesnt worked because compiler said it should be char* not string. And I asked "compare a string to a char" because I was pretty confused with string and chars. Now I learned that in C and C++ they are completely different.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For C++, use `std::string` and compare using `string::compare`.

For C use `strcmp`. If your (*i meant your programs*) strings (*for some weird reason*) aren't `nul` terminated, use `strncmp` instead.

But why would someone *not* use something as simple as `==` for `std::string`
?

Comment: Because `compare` has 3-way output `<0`, `0`, `>0`, whereas `==` has binary `true`/`false` output. Sometimes you need to take different action based on if the strings compare less or greater. A 3-way output lets you do that without comparing the strings twice.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you mean `std::string`, why not use the overloaded operators: `str1 == str2`, `str1 < str2`?

Comment: see my comment on ildjarn's post for why you would want something else.

Answer (score 4):

See [`std::basic_string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) and [`std::basic_string` operators reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) (in particular, there exists `operator==`, `operator!=`, `operator<`, etc.). What else do you need?

Comment: you could also betrying to figure out if a string is equal, greater, or less than another string all in one go (think which branch to descend down for a tree structure), in which case a strcmp like function is the more useful.

Comment: @diverscuba23 : Fair point indeed. :-] In which case, there is still `std::string::compare`, which should be preferred over `strcmp` in C++ for the reason @Paul R commented. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

When using C++ use C++ functions viz. `string::compare`. When using C and you are forced to use `char*` for string, use `strcmp`

Answer (score 1):

By your question, "is there a way to compare a string to a char?" do you mean "How do I find out if a particular char is contained in a string?" If so,  the the C-library function:

```
  char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

will do it for you.

-- pete

Answer (score 1):

std::string can contain (and compare!) embedded null characters.

are*comp(...) will compare c-style strings, comparing up to the first null character (or the specified max nr of bytes/characters)

string::compare is actually implemented as a template basic_string so you can expect it to work for other types such as wstring

On the unclear phrase to "compare a string to a char" you can compare the char to *string.begin() or lookup the first occurrence (string::find_first_of and string::find_first_not_of)

Disclaimer: typed on my HTC, typos reserved :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a string object, simplier is == as explained above, but if you have to string(stuff), where stuff is char *, i would go with strcmp, at least i am sure is more performant (there are a different c++ compilers and different architectures, different optimizations, etc) . Using C stuff is not forbidden, if you don't mind to be the c++ guru.