# C++ Doubly linked list adding node in alphabetical order and value

Tags: c++, sorting, char, doubly-linked-list, alphabetical-sort

My task is a create doubly linked list and sort them according to their data, if new written node's data is equal to the one of the nodes' data in my doubly linked list, i should sort them in a alphabetical order but I am stuck in the function `strcmp(temp->name, newnode->name)`,
For example, I am trying to check if these values entered in order

1. Christian 250
2. Tom 200
3. Alex 250

My sorted doubly linked list give the output as

1. Alex 250
2. Christian 250
3. Tom 200

Here is example of my code

```
   struct node {
    int data;
    string name;
    node* left;
    node* right;

    node(int i = 0, string s = "", node* l = nullptr, node* r = nullptr) : data(i), name(s), left(l), right(r) {}
};

struct node* head = NULL;
struct node* tail = NULL;
```

at the top of the program

```
void insert(int newdata, string name)  // Used for insertion at the end of the linked list and make 
{                                      // the connection for each of the node
    node* newnode = new node();
    node* nodehead = head;
    newnode->data = newdata;
    newnode->name = name;
    newnode->right = NULL;

    if( head == NULL)
    {
        newnode -> left = NULL;
        head = tail = newnode;
    }
    else 
    {
        while (nodehead->right != NULL)
        {
            nodehead = nodehead->right;     
        }
            nodehead->right = newnode; // make the connection for each of them
            newnode->left = nodehead;
            tail = newnode; // and newly created node is our tail

            sorting(newnode); // then go the function to sort them 
    }
   
    cout << "New node is added " << newnode->name << " " << newnode->data << endl;
}
```

then sort them based on their comparison of their data and if they are equal i should check based on their alphabetical order

```
 void sorting( node *  &newnode) // ı call sorting function in the insertion function
    {
        node* temp = head;
        node* temp2 = newnode;
    
        int numtemp;
    
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            node* temp2 = temp->right;
            while (temp2 != nullptr)
            {       
                if (temp2->data > temp->data) // comparison of their data if newnode's data is larger 
                {
                    string strtemp = "";
                    numtemp = temp->data; // Change their number
                    temp->data = temp2->data;
                    temp2->data = numtemp;
    
                    strtemp = temp->name; // Change their name
                    temp->name = temp2->name;
                    temp2->name = strtemp;
                }
                else if (temp2->data = temp->data) // if newly data is equal to linked list data
                {
                    int ret;
                    ret =  strcmp(temp2->name, temp->name); // i tried to check their string comparison but it did not work
                }
                temp2 = temp2->right;
            }
            temp = temp->right;
        }        
    }
```

Comment: `ret =  strcmp(temp2->name, temp->name);` since you are using std::string you compare with `==` or `!=` ... [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)

Comment: It isn't clear to me why there are two functions here. You have the tuple of data (number and string). Find where those belong in the list, allocate a new node, wedge it into that position, and be done with it. The list will always be "sorted" because that's how it was built in the first place.

Comment: @drescherjm sorry ı dont get your point, firstly what std::string means and second how can i use strcmp in this case

Comment: @Razbolt If you do not know what std::string is then why are you using it?!

Comment: `strcmp()` is for c-strings (char* ) not `std::string`. There is more information here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492485/strcmp-or-stringcompare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492485/strcmp-or-stringcompare)

Comment: @WhozCraig i can not find any other find to sort the datas based on their values, and then their names

Comment: @drescherjm okay ı see so how can ı compare each of them char ?

Comment: `if (temp2->name > temp->name) { // do something when temp2->name is greater } else { // do something when temp->name is greater or equal }`

Comment: @drescherjm ı tried like u say but aprreantly something goes wrong, it changes the whole linked list as same value    'code 'else if (temp2->data = temp->data)
            {
               if(temp2->name > temp->name ) 
               {
                   string strtemp = "";
                   strtemp = temp->name; // name change
                   temp->name = temp2->name;
                   temp2->name = strtemp;
               
               }
                
                 
                
            } 'code'

Comment: `else if (temp2->data = temp->data) ` assigns data, is doesn't compares: use `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison operator is bad:

```
              if(temp2->name < temp->name ) // make comparison but im not sure wheteris logical or not 
               {
                   string strtemp = "";
                   strtemp = temp->name; // name change
                   temp->name = temp2->name;
                   temp2->name = strtemp;
               
               }
```

Should be `<`.

Comment: Thanks buddy, the reason is you add  <  is reason of when checking these condition it takes the ASCII table values  ?

Comment: @Razbolt the ordering is done [lexicographically](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you define a comparison on the node itself, and use that in sorting. Keep in mind that if you are comparing through pointers, you'll need to dereference (compare the nodes, not the pointers).

The standard library already has a way to do comparison based on multiple terms. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie

using std::tie ensures that you meet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings

I am, of course, assuming that std::string's comparison meets your need for alphabetical. If that's not the case, this may need a minor tweek.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct node {
    int data;
    std::string name;
    node* left;
    node* right;

    node(int i = 0, std::string s = "", node* l = nullptr, node* r = nullptr) 
        : data(i), name(s), left(l), right(r) 
    {}

    bool operator< (const node & rhs) {
        return std::tie(data, name) < std::tie(rhs.data, rhs.name);
    }
};

int main(){
    // simplistic demo
    node a { 21, "green" };
    node b { 21, "yellow" };
    node * p1 = &a;
    node * p2 = &b;
    bool less = (*p1) < (*p2);
    if (p1->data == p2->data) {
        if (*p1 < *p2) {
            std::cout << p1->name << " < " << p2->name << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << p1->name << " >= " << p2->name << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is a homework assignment and the student is not allowed to use those standard library utility to complete this assignment easily.

Comment: If someone isn't allowed to use the right library features, they are ALWAYS better off using the right library features, then retrofitting their own versions on the working code. Trying to fix bugs in your comparison is a lot easier when you already know everything else works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ı should make the comparsion in a lots of nodes so ı can not figure out how to manipulate these example as huge link list

Comment: @MPops yes this is assigment and ı should find another way of comparing strings

Answer (score 0):

ı basically add in the else if part if the values are same and change names but appreantly it changes whole list of numbers

```
void sorting( node *  &newnode) 
{

    node* temp = head;
    node* temp2 = newnode;

    int numtemp;


    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        node* temp2 = temp->right;
        while (temp2 != nullptr)
        {

            if (temp2->data > temp->data)
            {
                string strtemp = "";
                numtemp = temp->data; // num change
                temp->data = temp2->data;
                temp2->data = numtemp;

                strtemp = temp->name; // name change
                temp->name = temp2->name;
                temp2->name = strtemp;

            }
            else if (temp2->data == temp->data) // here is the change 
            {
               if(temp2->name > temp->name ) // make comparison but im not sure wheteris logical or not 
               {
                   string strtemp = "";
                   strtemp = temp->name; // name change
                   temp->name = temp2->name;
                   temp2->name = strtemp;
               
               }
                
                 
                
            }

            temp2 = temp2->right;
        }

        temp = temp->right;
    }

   

}
```

Comment: `else if (temp2->data = temp->data)` assigns data, is doesn't compares: use `==`. `else if (temp2->data == temp->data)`

Comment: @Manuel yes ı accidently wrote like this i changed it thanks but it still did not make any list of alphabetical order